# Search files for a list of keywords using command line?

Tags: bash, perl, command-line, ssh, command

I have a list of keywords in a txt file like this:

```
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
```

I need to search all of my files - EXCEPT for HTML and CSS files - for these keywords.

The only thing I need to know is which of the keyword DON'T appear inside any of the files.  I don't care about the ones that do or what files they are in.  I simply need to know which of the keywords aren't in any of the files.

Everything I've looked up keeps coming back with results about how to find keywords and outputs the files they are in.  I'm open to doing this through command line, Perl, or whatever is the easiest way to get it done.

It looks like these commands should work for finding files not containing my keywords:

```
grep -L "foo" *
```

or

```
ack -L "foo" *
```

But I don't know how to pull the keywords from my txt file or how to make it search all files except .html or .css

I'm running this on my server so I'm not really too concerned about how resource-intensive it is...

Comment: Just updated with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your description is not as complete, I will assume the followings:

1. HTML file has .html extension (Note: it could have .htm .HTM, .HTML
   extension, I just assume on of them, please adapt the answer to suit
   your situation)
2. CSS file has .css extension (Again, it may have .CSS extension)
3. You keywords can be easily put into a grep command, i.e. NOT having
   special regular expression characters, for example "^" means starts
   of a line match, "$" means end of a line match.
4. You are trying to search for files under the a folder and its
   subfolder.
5. Assume your keyword file is ../keywordfile.txt.  Note: Since current
   folder search is assumed, your keywordfile.txt can not be placed in
   current folder, otherwise, searching keywordfile.txt itself yields
   all matches, and nothing will output (since every keyword matches)

Now a quick-and-dirty way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP=/tmp/filelist$$.txt
find . -type f | grep -v ".html$" | grep -v ".css$" > $TMP

## Note: if you are search only current fold but not subfolders,
## add "-maxdepth 1" option to "find" command

while read keyword; do
    if [ `while read file; do \
         cat "$file"; \
         done < $TMP | grep -c "$keyword"` -eq 0 ]; then \
      echo "$keyword does not appear in any files."; \
    fi; \
done < ../keywordfile.txt
```

Comment: Note: you must place this script in some other folder than the folder to search, otherwise, this script is ALSO searched for your keywords!

Comment: Here's the error I got:
`: command not found
: command not found
search.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
search.sh: line 14: `done < ../keywordfile.txt'`

Comment: It seems that your bash is old and does not honor some multi-line syntax.  Thus I added some `;`'s and  `\ `'s.

Comment: Limitation: file name with trailing space won't work.  File names with  leading spaces or spaces in-between should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

keywordlist=$(cat keywordfile.txt | tr "\n" "\|")
for x in $(find . ! -name "*.html" ! -name "*.css" -type f) 
do 
  if ! grep -qE "(${keywordlist%"|"})" $x
  then 
    echo $x
  fi
done
```